# Yeoman on Ubuntu with Vs Code issue (Aspnet Core)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, yeoman

I have created a Web App using Yeoman aspnet generator but I am not able to insert a new mvc controller to my app, I have tried to see

> yo aspnet --help

to see all the available generators but I cannot see

> aspnet:mvccontroller

I am only seeing one for nuget and one for web.config

Please help how can I add a controller from it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `yo` before the subgenerator `aspnet:MvcController`

The right command is `yo aspnet:MvcController ControllerName`

**UPDATE:**

The subgenerators are removed from generator during migration to RC version (now 0.3.* on NPM). I think you should add a controller manually in this last version.

Source: https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet/issues/934#issuecomment-286722058

Comment: Well in actual I am typing the whole command which you have given yo aspnet:MvcController ControllerName,

Comment: In the list of sub generators I dont see mvccontroller listed

Comment: added a screenshot, you can see there are no sub generators to do controllers using yo

Comment: If you look at this URL https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet you will notice that there are no mvc related sub-generators mentioned, why is that? is that the reason ?

Comment: I updated my aswer. The subgenerators are removed from aspnet generator in the last updates.